# Z3 giving unexpected result with the PDR engine

Tags: z3

I'm in the process of verifying properties about equations written in a synchronous programming language, by compiling said language to Z3, using the PDR engine. I use Z3 4.5.1 compiled from Github's master branch a week ago.

For your curiosity's sake, I use a derivative of the translation from the synchronous language Lustre to Z3 proposed in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/be85/edbb83f3533f42dd28cca41fd76484936c6b.pdf) (but it's not necessary to read it to understand what I want to do).

I have a problem with the following program, that returns `sat` while I think it should return `unsat`:

```
(declare-var out Int)
(declare-var next_out Int)
(declare-var mem Int)
(declare-var next_mem Int)
(declare-var ok Bool)
(declare-var next_ok Bool)
(declare-rel Init (Int Int Bool))
(declare-rel Trans (Int Int Bool Int Int Bool))
(declare-rel Main (Int Int Bool))
(declare-rel Error ())

(rule (=> (= mem 0) (Init out mem ok)))
(rule (=> (and (= next_ok (>= next_out 0))
               (= next_mem (+ mem 1))
               (= next_out mem))
          (Trans out mem ok next_out next_mem next_ok)))
(rule (=> (and (Init out mem ok)
               (Trans out mem ok next_out next_mem next_ok))
          (Main next_out next_mem next_ok)))
(rule (=> (and (Trans out mem ok next_out next_mem next_ok)
               (Main out mem ok))
          (Main next_out next_mem next_ok)))
(rule (=> (and (Main out mem ok)
               (not ok))
          Error))

(query Error :print-certificate true)
```

I'll try and simplify what's my intention so you don't have to go through the paper. We define three sequences `mem`, `out` and `ok` so that:

```
forall n > 0. mem(n) = mem(n - 1) + 1 with mem(0) = 0
and           out(n) = mem(n - 1)
and           ok(n) = out(n) >= 0
```

We want to prove that `forall n > 0. ok(n) = true`.

In the Z3 program, you can think of `mem`, `out` and `ok` as the values of the sequences at `n - 1` (or the memories containing the previous values of the sequences) and `next_*` as the values at `n`.

The `Init` relation states that the initial equations are correct (that is the equations for `n = 0`), in our case we just have `mem = 0` while `out` and `ok` are left free (that's rule 1). The `Trans` relation establishes that the relation between the `n`-th values and the `n - 1`-th values is correct (that's rule 2).

The `Main` relation states that, for a certain `n > 0`, the values of the sequences are coherent with the equations given (I'm not sure that's the best way of explaining it, if it's unclear please tell me). Thus rule 3 states that if the relations between the memories at `n = 0` and the relation between these memories and the new values at `n = 1` are correct, then we get a coherent set of values for `n = 1`. Rule 4 states that if we have a coherent set of sequence value at `n`, and that the relation between them and the values at `n + 1` is correct, then we get a new coherent set of sequence values at `n + 1`.

The last rule is the property we want to check: given a coherent set of values, we cannot have that `ok` is false.

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
(and (Main!slice!1 false) (not (>= (:var 5) 0)) (Main!slice!1 true))
```

and I can't understand why. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I continued to work on the problem, trying to understand what Z3 was doing with what I gave him.

I ran it with the option `fixedpoint.xform.inline_eager=false` which (I suppose) makes it inline less. When running with verbosity level 1, I saw that after the first application of `N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE` I had 5 rules instead of 3 (see below for the full output). I also had the following result :

```
unsat
(define-fun I ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (>= x!1 0))
(define-fun T ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool) (x!3 Int) (x!4 Int) (x!5 Bool)) Bool
  (and (<= (+ x!1 (* (- 1) x!4)) (- 1)) (= x!5 (>= x!1 0))))
(define-fun M ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (and x!2 (>= x!1 1)))
```

which is quite different from the original one… So unless I'm wrong about what the option above does, I guess it's a bug so I'll open an issue.

**Full output**

Running with `z3 <file> -smt2 -v:1`:

```
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...6 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog27mk_quantifier_instantiationE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog8mk_scaleE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog18mk_karr_invariantsE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog14mk_array_blastE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog12mk_bit_blastE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...3 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...3 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...3 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog8mk_sliceE...3 rules 0s)
Entering level 1
Entering level 2

2 query!0 closed
  true 1
 1 Main!slice!1 closed
   (not Main!slice!1_0_n) 182
  0 Main!slice!1 closed
    true 1
goals 0
sat
(and (Main!slice!1 false) (not (>= (:var 5) 0)) (Main!slice!1 true))
```

Running with `z3 <file> -smt2 -v:1 fixedpoint.xform.inline_eager=false`:

```
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...6 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog27mk_quantifier_instantiationE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog8mk_scaleE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog18mk_karr_invariantsE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog14mk_array_blastE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog12mk_bit_blastE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...5 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...5 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog13mk_coi_filterE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog25mk_interp_tail_simplifierE...5 rules 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog15mk_rule_inlinerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog22mk_subsumption_checkerE...no-op 0s)
(transform N7datalog8mk_sliceE...no-op 0s)
Entering level 1
Entering level 2
Entering level 3
(define-fun Init ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (>= x!1 0))
(define-fun Main ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (and (>= x!1 1) x!2))
(define-fun Trans ((x!0 Int)
 (x!1 Int)
 (x!2 Bool)
 (x!3 Int)
 (x!4 Int)
 (x!5 Bool)) Bool
  (and (<= (+ x!1 (* (- 1) x!4)) (- 1)) (= x!5 (>= x!1 0))))
unsat
(define-fun Init ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (>= x!1 0))
(define-fun Main ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Bool)) Bool
  (and x!2 (>= x!1 1)))
(define-fun Trans ((x!0 Int)
 (x!1 Int)
 (x!2 Bool)
 (x!3 Int)
 (x!4 Int)
 (x!5 Bool)) Bool
  (and (<= (+ x!1 (* (- 1) x!4)) (- 1)) (= x!5 (>= x!1 0))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was due to a bug that has now been fixed. The discussion [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1304) contains the commit correcting it.